# How to override setting in Zurb Foundation Framework. ie $topbar-bg .Sass

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to set a different color then the default black for the top bar, and I found that there is a variable that could be set to make this change but the way I am doing apparently does not make a difference.
I am using Visual Studio, with the nuget package and I also installed Compass to deal with SASS.
The Site.sass, I would imagine that would be the perfect place to do that so right after the @imports, I attempt to set the variable by doing the following

```
$topbar-bg: rgb(94, 136, 203);
```

But when I run the website, I see nothing different.
Is this the correct way of doing this? Does anyone have any suggestions? Should I just go ahead and change on the source (That does not seem right)?

Thanks all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compass documentation suggests that you set configuration variables prior to importing extensions:

http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configurable-variables/

Comment: Although is a little counter intuitive it worked, if I set the value before, I am actually instantiating a new variable, therefore, not overriding. ;) I wonder if this is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: It seems that Foundation does some work the moment it is imported. The result may be stored in some other variable, i haven't studied the code. If the configuration variable has not been set prior to import, Foundation uses a default value for it. After the import, the configuration variable is not used any more, that's why changing it's value won't do anything. PS Don't forget to upvote the answer and this comment. ;)